# Transaction stays in pg_stat_activity state after execution

Tags: postgresql, go, gorp

I'm quite new to both PostgreSQL and golang. Mainly, I am trying to understand the following:

- Why did I need the Commit statement to close the connection and the other two `Close` calls didn't do the trick?
- Would also appreciate pointers regarding the right/wrong way in which I'm going about working with cursors.

---

In the following function, I'm using `gorp` to make a CURSOR, query my Postgres DB row by row and write each row to a writer function:

```
func(txn *gorp.Transaction, 
     q string,
     params []interface{}, 
     myWriter func([]byte, error)) {

    cursor := "DECLARE GRABDATA NO SCROLL CURSOR FOR " + q
    _, err := txn.Exec(cursor, params...)
    if err != nil {
        myWriter(nil, err)
        return
    }

    rows, err := txn.Query("FETCH ALL in GRABDATA")
    if err != nil {
        myWriter(nil, err)
        return
    }

    defer func() {
        if _, err := txn.Exec("CLOSE GRABDATA"); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error while closing cursor:", err)
        }
        if err = rows.Close(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error while closing rows:", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("\n\n\n Closed rows without error", "\n\n\n")
        }
        if err = txn.Commit(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error on commit:", err)
        }
    }()

    pointers := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    container := make([]sql.NullString, len(cols))
    values := make([]string, len(cols))
    for i := range pointers {
        pointers[i] = &container[i]
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        if err = rows.Scan(pointers...); err != nil {
            myWriter(nil, err)
            return
        }

        stringLine := strings.Join(values, ",") + "\n"
        myWriter([]byte(stringLine), nil)
    }
}
```

In the `defer` section, I would initially, only `Close` the `rows`, but then I saw that `pg_stat_activity` stay open in `idle in transaction` state, with the `FETCH ALL in GRABDATA` query.

Calling `txn.Exec("CLOSE <cursor_name>")` didn't help. After that, I had a `CLOSE GRABDATA` query in `idle in transaction` state...

Only when I started calling `Commit()` did the connection actually close. I thought that maybe I need to call Commit to execute anything on the transation, but if that's the case - how come I got the result of my queries without calling it?

Comment: you want to end transaction, not close a declared cursor

Comment: remember to check rows.Error [see Handling Errors](http://go-database-sql.org/errors.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to end transaction, not close a declared cursor. `commit` does it.
[you can run multiple queries in one transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html) - this is why you see the result without committing.

the `pg_stat_activity.state` values are: `active` when you run the statement (eg, `begin transaction;` or `fetch cursos`), `idle in transaction` when you don't currently run statements, but the transaction remains begun and lastly `idle`, after you run `end` or `commit`, so the transaction is over. After you disconnect the session ends and there's no row in `pg_stat_activity` at all...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I `commit` the transaction, should I still close the declared cursor and `rows.Close()`?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html `WITHOUT HOLD` is default, so If you did not explicitly define otherwise - cursor will be lost on commit, yes